# Is it good practice to create static methods in MainActivity in Android?

Tags: java, android, static, singleton

I have a simple function that receives an integer 'cents' and returns a String with a decimal point between the units and the cents.

```
 1000 --> String function(int cents) --> "10.00"
```

This function is used extensively throughout the application and I am looking for a way not to replicate the code everywhere I use it.

I have thought of including this function as a **static method** inside MainActivity and then calling it like this:

```
 MainActivity.function();
```

Another possibility I have considered is creating an Object using the Singleton Pattern and accessing this function through it.

What are the best practices concerning this problem?

Comment: the static method is fine. It is not bound to the single instance, so you can use it in different places. I usually have an helper class for this kind of situations. In your case could be `ConverterHelper.java`

Comment: If you have an application Singleton class and it's only one or a few methods that you will be using, you can put it there. Otherwise I would create a seperate class for conversion.

Comment: The singleton doesn't feel right for this use case. Don't create singleton around classes that extends Acitivity